# How can I optimize the following MySQL query to achieve concurrent calls per seconds?

Tags: mysql, json

The following query read data from DB1.Data table, the query working correctly but is very slow.
This query result is concurrent calls from CDR information.

**Mysql query**

```
select sql_calc_found_rows H,M,S,(TCNT+ADCNT) as CNT from
(
select H,M,S,sum(CNT) as TCNT,
(
select 
count(id) as CNT
from DB1.Data force index (datetimeOrgination)  where 1=1 and 
(datetimeOrgination<UNIX_TIMESTAMP(concat('2018-02-09',' ',T1.H,':',T1.M,':',T1.S))  and (datetimeOrgination+callDuration)>UNIX_TIMESTAMP(concat('2018-02-09',' ',T1.H,':',T1.M,':',T1.S))) 
  and (DB1.Data.datetimeOrgination between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-09 00:00:00') and UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-09 23:59:59'))   
) as ADCNT 
 from 
(
(select 
hour(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination)) as H,
minute(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination)) as M,
second(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination)) as S,
count(id) as CNT  
from DB1.Data where 1=1  and (DB1.Data.datetimeOrgination between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-09 00:00:00') and UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-09 23:59:59'))    
group by hour(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination)),minute(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination)),second(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination)))

Union  all

(select 
hour(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination+callDuration)) as H,
minute(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination+callDuration)) as M,
second(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination+callDuration)) as S,
count(id) as CNT 
from DB1.Data  force index (datetimeOrgination) where 1=1 and  
(second(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination+callDuration))>second(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination)))   and (DB1.Data.datetimeOrgination between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-09 00:00:00') and UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-09 23:59:59'))    
group by hour(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination+callDuration)),minute(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination+callDuration)),second(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination+callDuration)))
) as T1  group by H,M,S
) as T2;
```

Here's the explain output

[image: Explain query]

This is the query output in JSON format:

```
{
"meta": {
    "count": 18,
    "totalCount": 18
},
"calls": [{
    "H": 10,
    "M": 30,
    "S": 44,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 11,
    "M": 27,
    "S": 1,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 11,
    "M": 28,
    "S": 44,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 12,
    "M": 23,
    "S": 52,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 12,
    "M": 29,
    "S": 27,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 12,
    "M": 30,
    "S": 38,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 14,
    "M": 26,
    "S": 17,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 14,
    "M": 26,
    "S": 44,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 14,
    "M": 26,
    "S": 51,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 14,
    "M": 27,
    "S": 2,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 14,
    "M": 27,
    "S": 8,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 14,
    "M": 40,
    "S": 27,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 14,
    "M": 40,
    "S": 57,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 14,
    "M": 40,
    "S": 58,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 15,
    "M": 8,
    "S": 4,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 15,
    "M": 8,
    "S": 31,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 15,
    "M": 56,
    "S": 38,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 16,
    "M": 27,
    "S": 30,
    "CNT": 1
}]
```

}

The first record in result

```
  "H": 10,
    "M": 30,
    "S": 44,
    "CNT": 1
```

shows we have 1 concurrent call at 10:30:44

---

**More details**

For calculate the concurrent calls per seconds, we should count 3 type of calls per second.

For example, if we want to calculate concurrent calls for 10:51:20 we need to count all of the following:

Step 1-Count all calls started at 10:51:20

Step 2-Count all calls ended at 10:51:20, but not started in the same second(20).

Step 3-Count all calls started before 10:51:20 and ended after 10:51:20.

Step 4- Finally needs to sum all of them to calculate the concurrent calls.

This query is for Step 1

```
(select 
hour(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination)) as H,
minute(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination)) as M,
second(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination)) as S,
count(id) as CNT  
from DB1.Data where 1=1  and (DB1.Data.datetimeOrgination between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-09 00:00:00') and UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-09 23:59:59'))    
group by hour(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination)),minute(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination)),second(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination)))
```

This query is for Step 2

```
(select 
hour(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination+callDuration)) as H,
minute(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination+callDuration)) as M,
second(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination+callDuration)) as S,
count(id) as CNT 
from DB1.Data  force index (datetimeOrgination) where 1=1 and  
(second(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination+callDuration))>second(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination)))   and (DB1.Data.datetimeOrgination between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-09 00:00:00') and UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-09 23:59:59'))    
group by hour(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination+callDuration)),minute(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination+callDuration)),second(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination+callDuration)))
```

This query is for Step 3 from the union result of 2 previous query

```
(
select 
count(id) as CNT
from DB1.Data force index (datetimeOrgination)  where 1=1 and 
(datetimeOrgination<UNIX_TIMESTAMP(concat('2018-02-09',' ',T1.H,':',T1.M,':',T1.S))  and (datetimeOrgination+callDuration)>UNIX_TIMESTAMP(concat('2018-02-09',' ',T1.H,':',T1.M,':',T1.S))) 
  and (DB1.Data.datetimeOrgination between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-09 00:00:00') and UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-09 23:59:59'))   
) as ADCNT
```

This query gathers all of them and returns the final result.

```
select sql_calc_found_rows H,M,S,(TCNT+ADCNT) as CNT from
(
```

As I mentioned before, that query working but very slow and complex, I know needs optimization and simplification.

---

Field types

```
`datetimeOrgination` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT
`callDuration` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

and indexs

```
INDEX `datetimeOrgination` (`datetimeOrgination`),
INDEX `callDuration` (`callDuration`),
```

Comment: "Concurrent calls" and "Calls per second" are _not_ the same values.  Do you want both?

Answer (score 3):

Caveat:  Some of my suggestions are for clarity or simplification, not necessarily for speed.

Potential bug:  `and  (second(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination+callDuration)) > second(from_unixtime(datetimeOrgination)))` does not make much sense.  It will catch a 2-second call that started at 11:22:00, but not one that started at 11:21:59.  Is that really what you wanted?  In any case, please explain what the query is trying to do.

Don't work with H,M,S, work with just seconds -- either by extracting the hh:mm:ss string from the date, or by getting the time of day in seconds.  Convert to H,M,S as the *last* step, not the *first*.

Don't `FORCE INDEX` -- it may help today, but hurt tomorrow.

Change `and  (DB1.Data.datetimeOrgination between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-09 00:00:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-02-09 23:59:59'))` to

```
  AND  DB1.Data.datetimeOrgination >= '2018-02-00'
  AND  DB1.Data.datetimeOrgination  < '2018-02-00' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

(Again, that is for clarity, not speed.)

Use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(id)`

I'm doing a lot of guessing; help us out by providing `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It smells like you are using the wrong datatype for `datetimeOrgination`.

After converting to seconds (from H,M,S), this

```
 datetimeOrgination < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(concat('2018-02-09',' ',',T1.H,':',T1.M,':',T1.S)
```

becomes something like

```
 datetimeOrgination < '2018-02-09' + INTERVAL secs SECOND
```

Even better would be to extract the datetime from the subquery and move to something like

```
 datetimeOrgination < datetime_from_subquery
```

This *may* give a better chance of using the index.

Cleanup the code and explain the goal; I'll try to come up with some more speedups.

Comment: yes, i "second" the motion that points out the peculiar the `SECOND() > SECOND()` expression... thats doing something, but seems like a really odd thing to do... ignoring the minutes, and just comparing the seconds. I also nod my head in agreement that the specification is unclear... OP says the query is returning a correct result... if that's true, thats either happening by accident, or its an extremely odd specification.

Comment: Probably just `callDuration > 0` is needed.

Comment: I edited the question and added more information about that query, needs, and table structure.

Answer (score 1):

(Since the definition of the problem is moving, I am starting a new Answer.)

The number of calls (of all types) at a *specific* point in time is simply:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl
    WHERE call_start            <= '2018-02-14 15:11:35'
    WHERE call_start + duration >= '2018-02-14 15:11:35';
```

But, I will quibble that the answer is "high" because it does not take into account what part of the given second the call started or ended.  So, I think this is closer to correct:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl
    WHERE call_start            <  '2018-02-14 15:11:35'
    WHERE call_start + duration >= '2018-02-14 15:11:35';
```

This should come as close as possible to saying how many concurrent calls happened at exactly '2018-02-14 15:11:35.000000'; it is an approximation of the number for '2018-02-14 15:11:35.5'.

By changing `COUNT(*)` to `SUM(...)` (as already discussed), you can get the count for a given type of call.

Then you add `GROUP BY` using datetime or timestamp arithmetic to finish out the task.

**One day**

To catch all calls that *started* during a single day:

```
WHERE call_start >= '2018-02-09'
  AND call_start  < '2018-02-09' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

**Problem Definition is wrong**

> For calculate the concurrent calls per seconds, we should count 3 type
>   of calls per second...

I contend that that is mathematically wrong.

"Concurrent calls" is at an instant, not across a whole second (or hour or day).  It means "how many phone connections are in use at that instant.

Let me change the statement of the problem to "concurrent calls per hour".  Does that make sense?  You *can* ask about "calls per hour", which could be interpreted as "calls *initiated* per hour" and be computed via `datetimeOrgination` and a `GROUP BY`.

Suppose I calls at the start of each minute, and each lasted 59 seconds.  A single phone line could handle that.  I suggest that is "1 concurrent call".

In contrast, what if I had 60 people all starting their 59-second calls at noon.  That would take 60 phone lines.  That would be 60 concurrent calls during the busy time of the day.

The metric you have involves a `datetimeOrgination` that is truncated (or rounded?) to a 1-second boundary.

Not let me modify the example to better explain why your 3 steps are wrong.  I want to group by hour, and I am willing to measure the number of calls at the top of the hour.  In particular, let's look at the 10 o'clock hour.

- 09:55 - 10:05 -- a 10-minute call that is counted, by your algorithm in each of 09 and 10 hours.
- 10:20 - 10:30 -- a 10-minute call that is counted, by your algorithm in only the 10 hour.

Why should a 10-minute call be counted as belong to two hours?  This inflates the "concurrency" count.

- 09:05 - 10:55 -- a 110-minute call that is also counted in each of 09 and 10 hours.
- 09:30 - 11:30 -- a 110-minute call that is also counted 3 hours.  Again, over-counting.

So, I contend that the only reasonable computation is to

Step 1-Count all calls started at 10:51:20 -- counted as happening at the :20 instant.

Step 2-Count all calls ended <strike>at</strike> *before* 10:51:20, but not started in the same second(20). -- *not* counted for :20.

Step 3-Count all calls started before 10:51:20 and ended after 10:51:20. -- counted for the :20 instant.

My suggested solution achieves that modification, and is both simpler and mathematically 'correct'.

Comment: Great Rick, the first query works, and I compared it with the old query result, and the output is the same. (only calculation of concurrent calls).

But I need the query return that data between two dates, for example, 2018-02-09 00:00:00 and   2018-02-09 23:59:59 and return the same result as I mentioned before (H, M, S, CNT).

is it possible to change that query to achieve that goal?

Comment: @RezaMousavi - I would expect the `COUNTs` to be different for _some_ edge cases of start/end being exactly the time in question.  Did your test include such?

Comment: @RezaMousavi - As for the full day query, do you want a call that spans midnight to be included?  If so, it will be counted in two days; is that OK?

Comment: Rick, I tested all situation with real data, the first query calculate correctly and the second one is not correct.
Also, not need includes the midnight expand, only the full day from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 works for me.

Comment: @RezaMousavi - I added "One day".

Comment: But I need the query return that data between two dates, for example, 2018-02-09 00:00:00 and 2018-02-09 23:59:59 and return the same result as I mentioned before (H, M, S, CNT), and not for static date and time.

Exactly I need a query return the result like this( the inputs only 2018-02-09 00:00:00 and 2018-02-09 23:59:59  means we need concurrent calls report between that dates in seconds resolution).
 Is it possible to change that query to achieve that goal?

Comment: {
    "H": 10,
    "M": 30,
    "S": 44,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 11,
    "M": 27,
    "S": 1,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 11,
    "M": 28,
    "S": 44,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 12,
    "M": 23,
    "S": 52,
    "CNT": 1
}, {
    "H": 12,
    "M": 29,
    "S": 27,
    "CNT": 1
},

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165328/discussion-between-reza-mousavi-and-rick-james).